# SQL error on UPDATE view with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view

This is the view

```
SELECT src.OfferAngebotsnummer AS OAngNr1, 
       SUM(src.Summe2) AS Summe,  
       CSDokument_1.OfferAngebotsnummer AS OAngNr2,  
       CSDokument_1.Auftragsvolumen
FROM (
     SELECT OfferAngebotsnummer, 
            ROUND(Angebotssumme, 2) AS Summe2
     FROM dbo.CSDokument
     WHERE (MANeu = 'AS400') AND 
           (Art = '3') AND 
           (DokumentTyp = '3')) AS src 
     INNER JOIN
           dbo.CSDokument AS CSDokument_1 ON 
           src.OfferAngebotsnummer = CSDokument_1.OfferAngebotsnummer
     GROUP BY src.OfferAngebotsnummer,
                    CSDokument_1.OfferAngebotsnummer, 
                    CSDokument_1.Auftragsvolumen
```

And this is the `UPDATE` statement

```
update UpdateAuftragsvolumenAngebot
set Auftragsvolumen = Summe
where Auftragsvolumen <> Summe
```

But I get an error that it's not allowed to use `UPDATE` on view with `group by` clause.

```
Cannot update the view or function 'UpdateAuftragsvolumenAngebot' 
because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, 
or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.
```

How can I accomplish the `UPDATE`?

Comment: It is happening because of the way view is created. Find original table and update values is the safest way. Or we need to modify view.

Comment: In the above view I've mixed a SELECT query with a table. I think I'll INSERT now the query in a table first. Make then a new view with the two tables and run the update on this view. I'll update my questions when it works this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using the view and just move it into a correlated sub-query like the below.  I suggest that because as soon as you aggregate a view you cannot update the underlying tables.

```
update CSDokument
set Auftragsvolumen = Summe
from CSDokument
inner join 
    (
    SELECT OfferAngebotsnummer, 
            ROUND(Angebotssumme, 2) AS Summe2
     FROM dbo.CSDokument
     WHERE (MANeu = 'AS400') AND 
           (Art = '3') AND 
           (DokumentTyp = '3')) AS src 
     INNER JOIN
           dbo.CSDokument AS CSDokument_1 ON 
           src.OfferAngebotsnummer = CSDokument_1.OfferAngebotsnummer
     GROUP BY src.OfferAngebotsnummer,
                    CSDokument_1.OfferAngebotsnummer, 
                    CSDokument_1.Auftragsvolumen
    ) as s
    on s.OfferAngebotsnummer = CSDokument.OfferAngebotsnummer
where CSDokument.Auftragsvolumen <> s.Summe
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I don't understand is you say "not using the view" but update "UpdateAuftragsvolumenAngebot"? Also I get a syntax error in the GROUP BY part. Is it neccessary to create "UpdateAuftragsvolumenAngebot" first in some other way than a view?

Comment: Yea, so what I meant is take the view and put it into the inner join ( view logic here) as s... I changed my above logic a bit to help out more.  I am not sure what the PK of CSDokument is so hard to tell if this will work properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the group by in your sub-query and not at the join stage.